# FireBase Authentication with Xamarin

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

Having some trouble with Firebase Authentication in a Xamarin Forms application being developed.  When trying to sign in using the following:

Interface:

```
public interface IFirebaseAuthenticator
{
    Task<string> LoginWithEmailPassword(string email, string password);
}
```

Class:

```
public class FirebaseAuthenticator : IFirebaseAuthenticator
{ 
    public async Task<string> LoginWithEmailPassword(string email, string password)
    {

            IAuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
            var token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);
            return token.Token;
```

The function is being called in the MainActivity.cs file of the application.  We do have the Xamarin.Firebase.Auth Nuget package installed and referenced.

Nothing is returned, and the error documentation isn't helpful at all.  Our team has gone through just about every bit of information we could find online and have resorted to posting here as a last resort.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say nothing is returned. Do you mean user is null?

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts:

1) What sign-in providers do you have enabled on Firebase? You'll need the Email/Password combo activated (this can be found under Develop > Authentication > Sign-in method).

2) How are you initialising your FirebaseAuth instance? Here's a sample that works for me:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .SetApiKey("your-api-key")
    .SetApplicationId("your-application-id")
    .Build();

// declared in the Activity class, ergo 'this' references the Activity's context
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);

FirebaseAuth authInstance = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app);

// Now you can use authInstance.SignInWith...(etc.)
```